# delete row in table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Apologies if something similar has been posted but I am trying to delete a row the button is on and not just the last row as the search results seem to give me.

I have the following code that adds to an HTML table but `onclick` doesn't work, the delete button doesn't work and addRow doesn't function. Why not?

**java code**

```
function addRow() {

  var table = document.getElementById("createOrderTable");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  ... other cells ...

  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var btn = document.createElement("input");
  btn.type = "button";
  btn.value = "Close";
  btn.onclick = deleteRow('createOrderTable', rowCount);
  cell4.appendChild(btn); 

}

function deleteRow(id, row) {
  document.getElementById(id).deleteRow(row);
}
```

**table code**

```
<table id="createOrderTable" width="100%">                   
  <tr>
    <th>Count</th><th>Product</th><th>Mesh</th><th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>OL</td><td>200</td><td><button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" onclick="deleteRow('createOrderTable', 1)">&times;</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

if I change

`btn.onclick = deleteRow('createOrderTable', rowCount );`

to

`btn.onclick = deleteRow('createOrderTable', rowCount + 1 );`

I can get the row to show but it throws

`Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'deleteRow' on 'HTMLTableElement': The index provided (3) is greater than the number of rows in the table (3).`

and doesn't show the button. I'm confused about what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You know what is the difference between function call and a reference? Just apply that knowledge, when you assign an event handler to `btn`.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean Teemu, I come from Java and am new to this way of doing things.. how can i reference a function with parameters?

Comment: You wrap the invokation in a function expression: `function () {deleteRow('createOrderTable', rowCount);}`. Please read also Maxali's answer, they have pointed an important issue too.

Comment: Ah that worked, and its functioning now. I am looking at Maxali's answer right now and his changes are having some unintended side effects but I'll post those down there.

Comment: Wait! There will be more problems. After adding a couple of rows you'll remove some of them randomly (i.e. not always the last-one). `rowCount` will point to a row position which it had when it was created, but that position might be wrong at the time you remove a row. I'd get `parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex` of the clicked button, and used that as an index to pass to `table.deleteRow` method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I was trying this out and it seemed to want to delete a row randomly and I couldn't figure out the pattern, i"ll try this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row index is not static, so as you delete rows, the row index of remaining rows can change if a row with a lower index is deleted. A solution is to not use rowIndex at all, and just use DOM relationships instead.

You can get a reference to the button that was clicked by passing *this* to the function, then go up parent nodes until you reach a TR element and delete it, e.g.

```js
// Helper function:
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();

  while (el && el.parentNode) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  }
  return null;
}    

function deleteRow(el) {
  var row = upTo(el, 'tr')
  if (row) row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>OL</td><td>200</td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">&times;</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td><td>AB</td><td>400</td>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">&times;</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also use event delegation and put a single listener on the table, then use the associated event object's *target* property to see if the event was initiated by a click on a button with class *close*. If so, call *deleteRow* and pass the element reference as a parameter as for the above.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

[Check working example.](http://codepen.io/maxali/pen/yePGvZ?editors=101)

To delete the current row that the button belongs to
Change onclick of `<button>` to :

```
onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)"
```

or change button in html like:

```
<input type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">X</button>
```

or by JavaScript code using

```
btn.setAttribute('onclick','deleteRow(this)');
```

Delete function is like:

```
function deleteRow(el) {
    var tbl = el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var row = el.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;

    tbl.deleteRow(row);
}
```

Comment: There is an initial row provided, but that can also be deleted.

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined` is there too many parent nodes?

Comment: @Maxali I understand your live example but that ignores that I'm adding rows to the table programmatically via the addRows function.

Comment: @john You add rows in your normal way. But set onclick event like `btn.setAttribute('onclick','deleteRow(this)');` instead of `btn.onclick`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101133/discussion-between-maxali-and-john).

Answer (score 1):

You shoud modify your code like this:

```
btn.onclick = deleteRow;
```

And the `deleteRow` declaration to this:

```
function deleteRow() {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
}
```