# How do I clear the rows in dynamically generated table?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, delete-row

I have a table that gets generated dynamically by fetching content from arrays stored in the `localStorage`.

Unfortunately, I noticed that every time the script is run, it appends to the existing table in the DOM as illustrated in the following images below:

The first time the script runs, the below is what is yielded:

[image]

The second time the same script is run, below is what is yielded:

[image]

Find below the script that generates the table above:

```
var array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactionData'));
var table = document.getElementById("table");

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);             
    currentTransaction = array[i];

    for (var b = 0; b < keys.length; b++) {
        var cell = newRow.insertCell(b);
        cell.innerText = currentTransaction[keys[b]];

        if (keys[b] == "statusIcon") {
           console.log("keys[b] value is: " +currentTransaction[keys[b]] );
           cell.innerHTML = currentTransaction[keys[b]];
            } 
       else {
           cell.innerText = currentTransaction[keys[b]];
            }
     }
}
```

This is my HTML code for the table:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To resolve this issue, I am trying to write a script that clears the existing rendered table in DOM **BEFORE** running the table generating script.

Find below my script to clear the rows:

```
var array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactionData'));
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var rowCount = array.length;;

for (var i = rowCount; i > 0; i--) {
    table.deleteRow(i);

}
```

Before the script is run, the table looks like this:

[image]

After this script is run I see this:

[image]

...and I also get the error message below:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'deleteRow' on 'HTMLTableElement':
The index provided (5) is greater than the number of 
rows in the table (5).
```

Can someone kindly point out what's wrong with my script and how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Where is the part of code where you store the table in localStorage ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886110/delete-row-in-table-with-javascript

Comment: to prevent the error you should probably do `rowCount = array.length-1;`, but why don't you just set `document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = null;`?

Comment: @exside Thanks, but `rowCount = array.length-1;` didnt work, I had to decrease the number to `-3` like this `rowCount = array.length-3;` for it to clear the table.  Furthermore, although the  `document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = null;` solution is a brilliant one, the reason why I don't use it is because this erases the entire table along with the `<thead>` row,  which I need to remain.

Comment: Why don't you put the data cells in a `tbody` tag, then you could just `null` out the table body, no loop necessary =)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To empty the body `<tbody>` of the table, excluding the table `<thead>`. 
I gave the table body `<tbody>` a `id="tableBodyContent"`.

View the updated HTML code below:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableBodyContent">
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

At the beginning of the dynamic table script, I run a script that reads in the value of the table body: `<tbody id="tableBodyContent">`, nullifies it, and resets it with the default values.

View the updated script below:

```
var bodyContent = document.getElementById("tableBodyContent");
console.log("Check this out: " +bodyContent.innerHTML);
bodyContent.innerHTML = "";
bodyContent.innerHTML = "<tr> </tr>";


var array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactionData'));
var table = document.getElementById("table");

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);             
currentTransaction = array[i];

for (var b = 0; b < keys.length; b++) {
    var cell = newRow.insertCell(b);
    cell.innerText = currentTransaction[keys[b]];

    if (keys[b] == "statusIcon") {
       console.log("keys[b] value is: " +currentTransaction[keys[b]] );
       cell.innerHTML = currentTransaction[keys[b]];
        } 
   else {
       cell.innerText = currentTransaction[keys[b]];
        }
 }
}
```

The script above `console.logs`:

```
Check this out: <tr> </tr><tr><td><i class="fas fa-check-circle colorBlue">
</i></td><td>10</td><td>10:37am, Sun</td></tr><tr><td><i class="fas fa-
exclamation-triangle colorRed"></i></td><td>50000</td><td>10:36am, Sun</td>
</tr><tr><td><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle colorYellow"></i></td>
<td>50000</td><td>10:35am, Sun</td></tr><tr><td><i class="fas fa-exclamation-
triangle colorYellow"></i></td><td>60000</td><td>10:33am, Sun</td></tr><tr>
<td><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle colorRed"></i></td><td>50</td>
<td>10:25am, Sun</td></tr><tr><td><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle 
colorRed"></i></td><td>6332</td><td>10:24am, Sun</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should reconstruct your code. With the snippet below you can add the code when you want, or you can clear your table - when you want it. If you would like to delete single rows, then I would suggest giving them an ID (in the localStorage) and using it on the table rows.

```js
//var array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactionData'));

// mocking localStorage items
const array = [{
    status: 10,
    amount: 20,
    time: 30
  },
  {
    status: 20,
    amount: 30,
    time: 40
  },
  {
    status: 30,
    amount: 40,
    time: 50
  },
  {
    status: 40,
    amount: 50,
    time: 60
  },
  {
    status: 50,
    amount: 60,
    time: 70
  }
]

var tbody = document.querySelectorAll(".table tbody")[0];

// creating the table
function addTableRows(arr, container) {
  let html = ''
  arr.forEach(e => html += `<tr>${createTableRow(e)}</tr>`)
  return html
}

// creating a single row (tr) of the table
function createTableRow(obj) {
  return `<td>${obj.status}</td><td>${obj.amount}</td><td>${obj.time}</td>`
}

// initializing table
tbody.innerHTML = addTableRows(array, tbody)

// removing rows
document.getElementById('removeRows').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  tbody.innerHTML = ''
})

// adding rows
document.getElementById('addRows').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  tbody.innerHTML = addTableRows(array, tbody)
})
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="addRows">Add rows</button></br>
<button id="removeRows">Remove rows</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. You are on the right track. I would like only the body of my table to be cleared. I therefore thought the code `tbody.innerHTML = ' '` run in the browser console would remove the table body, but it didnt. What am I missing?

Comment: The code I presented clears the **tbody** element - in the **removeRows()** function. **tbody** is a variable only inside the snippet - you should put `document.querySelectorAll(".table tbody")[0].innerHTML = ''` in Chrome dev console - and see that it clears the table body.